# How to check if any string in array contains any other string (substring) in other array? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, arrays, string, postgresql, substring

I've got 2 string arrays, and I wanna to compare if any string of first array - contains SUBstring from other one, which storing these SUBstrings.

In other words: I don't wanna compare these arrays and their strings fully, I need to find exactly if strings from one array contains a SUBstrings from other array.

Comment: What you have tried  so far?

Comment: Well, I found out how to find one substring from array, but have no idea how to do it in one SELECT command with 2 arrays.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE array_to_string(Array1, ',') LIKE ANY(Array2) - nothing is output...

SELECT * FROM table WHERE POSITION(array_to_string(Array, ',') IN ANY(Array2) - here is a syntax error.

Comment: @zerocentaur . . . Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following approach, if the two arrays are not too big:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT unnest('{apple pie,sugar,brown sugar}'::varchar[]) a1) t1,
    (SELECT unnest('{pie,sugar}'::varchar[]) a2) t2
    where t1.a1 like ('%' || t2.a2 || '%')
```

Otherwise I suggest you to use ts_vectors and the full text search operators: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html

Comment: That's a great example, and works well! But what if the first array is a column?
```
    SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT unnest(MyColumn) a1) t1,
    (SELECT unnest('{"Smth1","Smth2"}'::text[]) a2) t2
    WHERE t1.a1 like ('%' || t2.a2 || '%')
```
That's throws "table is not exist".

Comment: Find a working example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/97cd1/1

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Finally I did exactly what I wanted to do! I'd like to get your rep up, but unforunately I can't.